# ssh to ubuntu server, /bin/bash: Exec format error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

When trying to ssh into a webserver, the connection opens and immediately closes with the following error

```
/bin/bash: Exec format error
Connection to ip.ip.ip.ip closed.
```

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: first try "ssh serverhostname /bin/ksh" if the ksh is installed

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: ssh serverhostname "readelf -e /bin/bash  | grep Class"

Comment: Gives the same error